# Adding Push Notifications with EasyApns

Tags: php, swift, xcode, push-notification, ios10

I am trying to setup a notifications server in PHP using EasyApns.com and by following this tutorial: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/building-your-own-push-notifications-server/

Part of the setup of App Delegate requires that we send three variables to the php script (for saving in the DB) which show whether sound, badges and alerts are enabled or disabled.

However I cannot work out how to extract this data in IOS10's UNNotificationCenter

I have this method:

```
let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in  
    self.pushSound = settings.alertSetting.rawValue
    self.pushAlert = settings.soundSetting.rawValue
    self.pushBadge = settings.badgeSetting.rawValue
}
```

All of which return the number 2. Unfortunately I cannot find out what this number refers to! I was expecting to find a boolean to show me whether they are enabled or disabled.

I know I am being an idiot as I am new to IOS development, but I would appreciate a pointer in the correct direction!

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider that 2 could mean true and one false?

Comment: I considered that, but it would be a complete guess, and if it were true or false, I think I would expect to see 0 and 1, not 1 and 2...

Comment: Maybe, on actual device, turn one to false in settings and see what is given. Also have you read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter. Possibly, 2 means it hasn't been established?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I didn't think of that. 1 is false, and 2 is true. Thank you.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Changing the settings and recording the different states worked, yes! I haven't managed to actually get the push notifications working, but that's another story! Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear!  Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One is False (Disabled)**
Why:

- Easier to understand during parsing.
- If in the case you had to divide to find a value for false, 0 would return error.
- One is the number of times for false if an audio is sounded. Ex: Click once for false, two for true.

**Two is True (Enabled)**
Why:

- Easier to read
- Two is the number of times for true if an audio is sounded. Ex: Click once for false, two for true.

Answer (score 0):

1 is false (disabled) and 2 is true (enabled)